# Excel 2013 Conditional Formatting with AND operator

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have an issue while trying to apply conditional formatting to a range of cells in Excel 2013.

My formular is

```
=AND(INDIRECT("N"&ROW()) >-60,INDIRECT("N"&ROW()) <-30)
```

and this applies to column C.  The value in column N of the row is -35 (negative 35).  This results in no formatting being applied.  However if I apply the individual tests seperatly both evaluate to true and the formatting is applied.

```
=INDIRECT("N"&ROW()) >-60

=INDIRECT("N"&ROW()) <-30
```

Both the above work ok seperatly.

If I reference an individual cell then the AND operator works fine

```
=AND($N$27 >-60,$N$27 <-30)
```

Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong and how to apply the above condition to a range using INDIRECT and ROW please or a better method?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `INDIRECT()` is unnecessary complicated.

Use `=AND($N27 >-60,$N27 <-30)` (note the removed `$` before the row number!), and Excel will apply it respectively to all cells - each cell will its corresponding row. When you type it in, use the row number of the active cell; Excel is clever enough to apply it realtive to that.